# How to fix "undefined reference" linker errors that occur in spite of passing the right flags?

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker-errors, pcap

I'm trying to compile [this C program called Pirni](http://code.google.com/p/n1mda-dev/source/browse/#svn/trunk/pirni), which was originally made for iPhone, and I would like to run it on linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It's very short, (3 C files and 1 header file). But I get the following errors. I do have `libpcap-dev` installed and I did include `-lpcap` so I don't know what could be wrong.

```
gcc -Wall -pthread -lpcap pirni.c threads.c sniffer.c -o pirni -lnet
pirni.c: In function ‘set_forwarding’:
pirni.c:31:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sysctlbyname’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
/tmp/cc3sf284.o: In function `set_forwarding':
pirni.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `sysctlbyname'
/tmp/ccvGjyMo.o: In function `processPacket':
sniffer.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `pcap_dump'
/tmp/ccvGjyMo.o: In function `initSniffer':
sniffer.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `pcap_open_live'
sniffer.c:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `pcap_lookupnet'
sniffer.c:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference to `pcap_compile'
sniffer.c:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `pcap_setfilter'
sniffer.c:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `pcap_dump_open'
sniffer.c:(.text+0x27c): undefined reference to `pcap_loop'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
gcc -Wall -pthread -lpcap pirni.c threads.c sniffer.c -o pirni -lnet
                   ^^^^^^
```

move that to the end, so the linker knows which symbols it should link.

With the library where it is in the command line, the linker sees that so far it doesn't need any symbols from `libpcap`, so ignores it.

Answer (score 6):

Say this:

```sh
gcc -Wall -pthread pirni.c threads.c sniffer.c -o pirni -lnet -lpcap
#                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Libraries need to be listed *after* the local translation units. Your `ld` manual will tell you in detail why (it has to do with how missing symbols are searched and inserted).